# Make 3 columns from bytes present in the text using shell commands

Tags: linux, shell-script, awk, sed, grep

I have a file `input.txt`, which contains several paragraphs as below:

```
[730480.910190] [MACSTATUSIND] ACTIND_ParseMACSTATUS:
[730480.910205] fe 0a 39 01 0a 00 51 e7 ba 9d c7 0d 00 00 00 00  ..9...Q....
[730480.910220] 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  ...........
[730480.910233] 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 xx xx xx xx xx xx  .....:bC.B.
[730480.910247] xx xx yy yy yy yy yy yy zz zz 64 34 e8 ff 00 00  ......d4...

[730480.910190] [MACSTATUSIND] ACTIND_ParseMACSTATUS:
[730480.910205] fe 0a 39 01 0a 00 51 e7 ba 9d c7 0d 00 00 00 00  ..9...Q....
[730480.910220] 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  ...........
[730480.910233] 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 aa bb cc dd ee ff .....:bC.B.
[730480.910247] gg hh ii jj kk ll mm nn oo pp 64 34 e8 ff 00 00  ......d4...
```

from above data, for each paragraph i want to make three columns, and then store those rows in a different/new file `new.txt`.

**Output: new.txt**

```
   col1    col2     col3
  -------  ----    ------
xxxxxxxx   | yyyyyy |  zzzz
aabb..gghh | ii..nn |  oopp
```

**Note**: The above paragraph log is repeated in the file many times. All the paragraphs should have start pattern with `[MACSTATUSIND] ACTIND_ParseMACSTATUS:`

Comment: How would one know the start and end of a paragraph?

Comment: @Inian All the paragraphs should have start pattern with  "[MACSTATUSIND] ACTIND_ParseMACSTATUS:"

Comment: Update that in the question and also update a proper paragraph with real values and update a sample output of it

Comment: post the filled output, not just the empty columns

Comment: @RomanPerekhrest  comments implemented in question

Comment: @Inian comments implemented ::

Comment: @SantoshSahu, the output is unclear: why does the 1st column has eight `x` characters and what does this `aabb..ffgg` mean?

Comment: @RomanPerekhrest aabbb..ffgg means aabbccddeeffgg(because of space issues, i wrote like that> the eight xx chracters are a different example like aabbccddeeffgghh with 8 characters

Comment: @SantoshSahu, still unclear. I wanted to help and the description is vague

Comment: This question is answered here  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48104329/grep-for-the-particular-bytes-and-put-into-columns-from-a-file-to-a-new-file-sh

Answer (score 0):

```
awk 'BEGIN { print "     col1        |     col2     | col3" }
    /^\[730480.910233\] / {SA = $12 $13 $14 $15 $16 $17}
    /^\[730480.910247\] / { print SA $2 $3 " | " $4 $5 $6 $7 $8 $9 " | " $10 $11}
'  input.txt > new.txt
```